# Excel VLOOKUP and FIND combination

Tags: excel

I have two columns, A and B, containing values. I want to insert values in a C column where each of these are contained in both A and B.

Example of my desired result:

```
A         B         C

Hello     No        No
Nothere   here      here
YesNo     ha
```

As "here" is contained in "Nothere", it must be added. Same as "No" in "YesNo"

As far as I know, I can use FIND to find out if the string exists and VLOOKUP to search for the entire column. But how can I use FIND in the entire column? Because with VLOOKUP I must search for a specific value, and it will be changing from column to column.

How can I achieve this? (I don't need to use FIND nor VLOOKUP, I just mentioned this as research I was doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you sure can use `FIND`, or at least, its case insensitive equivalent: `SEARCH` (If you still want case sensitive search, use `FIND` instead of `SEARCH`).

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,$A$1:$A$3))),B1,"")
```

`SEARCH` first returns an array: `#VALUE!`, `1`, `4`

`ISNUMBER` then returns another array: `FALSE`, `TRUE`, `TRUE`

`--ISNUMBER` means those are converted to 1 and 0, 1 being TRUE and otherwise, so `0`, `1`, `1`.

`SUMPRODUCT` will sum the numbers in that array, which is in this case 2, which is considered as TRUE for excel, hence you get B1 as final result.

---

You can also use `MATCH`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&B1&"*", $A$1:$A$3, 0)), "", B1)
```

which might be simpler, or `VLOOKUP` if you want to stick with it:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&B1&"*", $A$1:$A$3, 1, 0)), "", B1)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. Just to know, Could I turn this into a macro? Or is there a way to make the values dynamic in order to use this in the future?

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini I don't know much about macros, it could probably be written in a more efficient way than using the function, I wouldn't know. As for the second question, can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: Sure. I'll use this formula a lot, because I perform this kind of process many times a day. I wanted to find a way to use this formula more efficiently, without having to change the values of the cells so often, because it can be problematic sometimes.

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini Oh, but you shouldn't have to change any values there and just drag the formula down, except for the range to lookup. You can make the range become `A:A`, which should make the first formula work slower, but the other two to a lesser extent.

Answer (score 2):

A short way....but needs "array entry"

`=IF(COUNT(FIND(B1,A$1:A$3)),B1,"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

As Jerry says, `FIND` is case-sensitive - you can replace with `SEARCH` if you don't want case-sensitivity

Comment: Once you have the formula in a cell select the cell then press `F2` key to select the formula then hold down `CTRL` and `SHIFT` keys and press `ENTER`. If done correctly you get curly braces like { and } around the formula

Answer (score 1):

use `VLOOKUP` and `FIND` those texts

```
"*No*" => "*"&B2"*"

"*here*" => "*"&C2"*"

"*ha*" => "*"&D2"*"
```

star `*` means replace any texts